# Bash script to transfer files to a server with user acces changing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, server

I want to connect and transfer files, from my machine to a server using ssh.

With my normal user, I can only have acces to certain directories. To have access to the destination file, i have to use the command: **sudo -su superUser** and now I can have access to transfer to the transfer directory.
Can I do that with my bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
file_to_upload="*.txt"
remote_username="normal.user"
remote_hostname="123.45.67.8.."

remote_destination_dir="/data/apps/transfer"

scp "$file_to_upload" "$remote_username@$remote_hostname:$remote_destination_dir"
```

After the transfer, scp is closing the connection, so I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: You can use `sshpass`.

Comment: This depends on the remote configuration, too. If you genuinely _only_ can switch users with `sudo` then no. If you are able to set up an SSH key for the privileged user then obviously what you are asking will work. But some sites disable this for security reasons, or simply by mistake.

Comment: I would talk to the server admin and ask what they recommend you to do.

Comment: They recommended to me this method, but I don't think it's possible. The best solution would be to ask for the superUser credentials and make the transfer with scp, without user changing and others..

Comment: Are you running `sudo` on the *local* computer, or the *remote* server?

Comment: I need to execute sudo on the remote server, to have acces to the /data/apps/transfer directory, with normal user I don't have access.